# Phase Shift Oscillator not Oscillating

Tags: oscillator

May I please ask why my phase shift oscillator as shown is not oscillating?
My R1=R2=R3, and C1=C2=C3.
I am trying to get around 1kHz of oscillation, so using the simple equation of fr=1/(2*pi*R*C*sqrt(6)), I get all the values as shown in the pictures.

But why is it not oscillating?
I tried at both Multisim and LTSpice, but it just doesn't simulate.
I am using ideal opamp at both simulators (gain is very high, 200x let say).
I put Rf(feedback resistor of opamp) to be 220k to have Rf>29*R, which will make the loop gain >1 (to fulfill the Berkhausen criteria), but it is still not oscillating. I thought the circuit fulfills both of the criterion for oscillating to happen?

I tried changing Rf to even higher value, and even play with the RC values. I also tried to use LM741 op amp and rise the supply voltage slowly, but I never get oscillation.
May someone please give me enlightenment on what is wrong/lacking?
Thank you very much.

[image: phase shift oscillator]

Answer (score 1):

For some oscillators, it helps to "kick-start" to get them going in a simulation that doesn't model the noise that gets a *real oscillator* going. In this case, the kick-start is done by initializing node n005 to 0.01V (anything other than zero volts). Node 5 is at the right-hand end of C3:
[image: A phase shift op-amp oscillator]

This oscillator uses a virtual op-amp with open-loop gain of 100K. Since it has no power supply and is perfectly linear, oscillations grow exponentially...forever.

```
XU1 N001 0 N002 opamp Aol=100K GBW=10Meg
R1 N002 N001 180k
R2 0 N003 560
R3 0 N004 560
R4 0 N005 560
C1 N003 N002 .1µ
C2 N004 N003 .1µ
C3 N005 N004 .1µ
R5 N001 N005 5.6k
.IC V(n005)=.01
.tran 0 .1 0 .00001
.lib opamp.sub
.backanno
.end
```

Your oscillator also hasn't quite enough phase shift.

Comment: Helloooooo Thank you! But may I ask whether that structure is different from what I am using? I think I need to use the structure that is in my picture above, since that structure is what is there in my textbook. Are they the same? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Prietess OK - your circuit *does oscillate* with a kick-start. I think that's your primary problem. For your circuit, you could apply 0.1 volt to "Vout" with an ".IC" directive. Another method of starting oscillations involves adding a very low amplitude AC voltage or AC current source to one of the feedback elements. The source could be a single large pulse instead.

Comment: I tried at Multisim with that initial condition, and strangely it still doesn't want to oscillate. It does oscillate when I used the same setup at LTSpice, like what you said. Why Multisim doesn't oscillate? I wonder. I put the same open loop gain and UGF of the opamp.

Answer (score 1):

I have simulated your circuit using Intusoft IsSpice as you can see below. The feedback resistance is calculated to compensate the attenuation where the phase lag is 180°. I derived the oscillation frequency here for the two phase-shifted oscillators (\$RC\$ and \$CR\$) here [Deriving the formula of oscillation frequency for the Phase Shift Oscillator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107496/deriving-the-formula-of-oscillation-frequency-for-the-phase-shift-oscillator/313270#313270). In a circuit like this, with perfect elements, there is no noise as correctly pointed out by glen_geek. You can crank the circuit with an external source but the easiest way is by using a .IC statement as I did on \$C_3\$:

[image]

When you run the simulation, it nicely oscillates as shown below at a frequency of 1.16 kHz. Please note that my feedback resistance (your \$R_4\$) is 162 k\$\Omega\$ and not 220 k\$\Omega\$ as in your circuit. Oscillations are nicely maintained without clipping so perfect compensation of the attenuation. Please make sure to check the UIC box (use initial conditions) before starting the simulation.

[image]

Please note that \$R_f\$ must *exactly* compensate the attenuation where the phase lag is 180°. The condition for oscillation is a 360° total phase lag (-180° of the \$CR\$ network plus -180° of the inverting op amp) and a gain of 1. If the gain is less than one then the poles have a real part and oscillations will cease quickly. If the gain is greater than 1, the the poles jump into the right-half plane and oscillations diverge until a real op amp rails up or down. So \$R_f\$ must be 29 times 5600 in your example to match this criteria: 162 k\$\Omega\$ not more, not less. See the two examples below with more than 162 k\$\Omega\$ and less than 162 k\$\Omega\$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change Vin(+) to Vcc/2 with 2 R's like 470K.  You are violating Vin CM range.

Then increase gain to make stable oscillation, let R4= 1M if you have enough GBW at fo.

Overall is a poor design at best, and worse when you dont consider GBW and attenuation and CM in range.