# How to calculate the frequency of oscillation of this low-pass phase shift oscillator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, low-pass, oscillation

In the following phase-shift oscillator a low pass network is used instead of a high-pass network.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL7phb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Usually the frequency of oscillation for a high pass is given by:

$$ f_{oscillation} = \frac{1}{2\pi RC\sqrt{6}}$$

However, I'm I don't really know how this is derived, I just use it. For the this circuit, how would one calculate the frequency of oscillation?

With the given values of R= 2.2Meg and C = 1uF, LTspice gave a frequency of about 0.174Hz.

(In the actual simulation I amplified Vsin)

Thank you.

Comment: Your circuit is flawed - C3 is ineffective because it connects between a virtual earth and actual circuit earth i.e. has zero voltas across it and therefore does not contribute to shifting phase. Try and find a valid circuit that uses low pass filters.

Comment: @Andyaka I got the circuit from http://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/simple-generator-provides-very-low-frequencydistortion-sine-and-square-waves. Is it wrong?

Comment: What part of my original comment did you not understand?

Comment: o_o what ? I think whoever drew this schematic interchanged  resistors and capacitors. C3 is unwanted too.

Comment: I think your equation would be far closer to correct ***if*** the \$\sqrt{6}\$ were moved from the denominator to the numerator. The reason is that in the ideal case, \$2\pi\:f\approx \operatorname{tan}\left(60^\circ\right)\$. But the case isn't ideal since the RC sections do load each other in practice, so I'd expect the frequency to be a bit higher than predicted from the ideal.

Comment: Ah! I think I see. The ideal case requires a gain > 8, here. So the frequency would be predictable as \$\frac{\operatorname{tan}\left(60^\circ\right)=\sqrt{3}}{2\pi\:R\:C}\$, if and only if the (+) were set to \$\frac{1}{8}\$th of \$V_\text{CC}\$. But you've set it to \$\frac{1}{2}\:V_\text{CC}\$. So this accounts for the additional \$\sqrt{2}\$ factor.

Comment: @Andyaka if there were zero volts across those inputs, all op amp outputs would be invariably zero. You are misapplying the virtual mass concept, methinks. Simulate the circuit and you will find out that it works and produces a nice square wave of nearly 2.4 seconds period. And across that last cap you'll get 60 mVpp (I used a shitty op-amp, one of those with less than infinity gain).

Comment: @AndyAka This isn't a virtual earth. If there was a feedback resistor from  (out) to (-in) , (-in) would become a virtual earth point. It is the negative feedback that makes it a virtual earth - the output moves opposing the input change, until it has been cancelled out, thus keeping it at earth.  In this circuit OA1 is a comparator, and its output will be a square wave. OA1 may be replaced by a CMOS invertor.

Comment: To those above and regards my earlier comment. Yes indeed you are both right.

Comment: You can have a look at a documented answer I gave [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107496/deriving-the-formula-of-oscillation-frequency-for-the-phase-shift-oscillator/313270#313270) but with a buffer compensating the insertion gain right at the 180° phase shift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your schematic uses a low pass filter approach. One way to mentally consider a solution is to look at the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7l4wg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Above, you can see that \$R_3\$ and \$Z_3\$ form a voltage divider that divides \$V_Y\$ into \$V_\text{OUT}\$. Also, \$R_2\$ and \$Z_2\$ form a voltage divider that divides \$V_X\$ into \$V_Y\$. Finally, \$R_1\$ and \$Z_1\$ form a voltage divider that divides \$V_\text{IN}\$ into \$V_X\$. It follows that:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Each Stage}
\left\{
  \begin{array}{rl}
V_\text{OUT} = V_Y\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_3}{Z_3}}&&Z_3 = Z_{C_3}\mid\mid \infty=Z_{C_3}\\\\
V_Y = V_X\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2}{Z_2}}&&Z_2 = Z_{C_2}\mid\mid \left(Z_3 + R_3\right)\\\\
V_X = V_\text{IN}\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_1}{Z_1}}&&Z_1 = Z_{C_1}\mid\mid \left(Z_2 + R_2\right)
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}$$
$$\therefore \frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_1}{Z_1}}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2}{Z_2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_3}{Z_3}}$$

Assuming \$R=R_1=R_2=R_3\$ and \$C=C_1=C_2=C_3\$ and setting \$\tau=R\:C\$ I get the following answer:

$$H\left(j\omega\right)=\frac{1}{1 - 5\:\left(\omega\:\tau\right)^2 + j\:\left[6\:\omega\:\tau-\left(\omega\:\tau\right)^3\right]}$$

For a phase shift of \$180^\circ\$, the imaginary part in the denominator goes to zero. So:

$$\begin{align*}6\:\omega\:\tau-\left(\omega\:\tau\right)^3&=0\\6\:\omega\:\tau&=\left(\omega\:\tau\right)^3\\6&=\left(\omega\:\tau\right)^2\\\omega&=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\tau}\\\therefore\\f&=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2\pi\:R\:C}\end{align*}$$

Note that this differs from what you wrote.

I just tried out a simulation on LTspice using a decent R2R opamp (it can't handle more than about \$12.5\:\text{V}\$ between its rails.) Here's the results:

[image]

The period seems to be about \$5.8\:\text{s}\$. Which is close to the prediction.

---

### Note

Per Tony's request, it's not difficult to work out the peak or peak-to-peak voltage for the resulting sine wave at the output.

Since the imaginary component of \$H\left(j\omega\right)\$ is 0, the magnitude is just \$\mid\:H\left(j\omega\right)\mid\:=\frac{1}{29}\$ (just plug in \$\omega=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\tau}\$.) The RMS of the square wave at \$V_\text{IN}\$ is just \$6\:\text{V}\$ (as it is always either \$+6\:\text{V}\$ or else \$-6\:\text{V}\$.) So the output will be:

$$V_{\text{OUT}_\text{RMS}}=\frac{1}{29}\cdot \text{V}_{\text{IN}_\text{RMS}}=\frac{1}{29}\cdot 6\:{\text{V}_\text{RMS}}\approx 207\:{\text{mV}_\text{RMS}}$$

Since the output is a sine wave, the peak should be about \$\sqrt{2}\$ larger, or \$\approx 290\:\text{mV}_\text{P}\$.

As you can see, the image I included above shows an output peak that is close to this prediction, as well.

Comment: i like your style of answers +1 and never tried Sage/Sympy

Comment: Bonus points however might also show the sine amplitude Vpp is 26 dB down from Vcc-Vee

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Um. Okay. I'll add a note since the added work is essentially zero.

Comment: A more general formula for the frequency, the long version that does not require all the R to be the same or all the C to be the same: $$f_\text{osc}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{\left(R_1+R_2+R_3\right)C_1+\left(R_2+R_3\right)C_2+R_3C_3}{R_1R_2R_3C_1C_2C_3}}$$

Comment: @ElEctric If your point is that one can use varying values for the resistors and capacitors and still get a useful oscillator then you have no argument from me. Did I say something that made you feel as though I felt all the R values had to be the same and that all the C values also had to be? If so, please let me know. (Just simple parasitics alone would mean none of these would ever work, if that were the case.) It's nice to add a formula to handle varying values -- interesting even -- but beyond the scope of my answer here. Perhaps you'd like to write a fuller exposition? I'd upvote it.

Comment: @jonk Here is the Mathematica code I used:

j=Sqrt[-1]

zc1=1/(j*w*C1)

zc2=1/(j*w*C2)

zc3=1/(j*w*C3)

z1=zc1

z2=1/(1/zc2+1/(R1+z1))

z3=1/(1/zc3+1/(R2+z2))

Factor[z1*z2*z3/((R1+z1)*(R2+z2)*(R3+z3))]

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to derive the oscillation frequency from this oscillator is to go back to Barkhausen's oscillation criteria. First find the transmittance of the 3 RC blocks and the one of your amplifier. Then apply Barkhausen's criteria for phase shift: the sum of the phase shifts from the two transmittance must be equal to zero for an oscillation to exist.

Since your amplifier has a real negative transmittance, its phase shift is equal to -180°. Hence the transmittance of the RC blocks must be a real negative number, which implies its imaginary value must be zero. From this condition, you may find out that \$ \omega RC = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \$, ending with 
\$ f = \frac{1}{2\pi RC \sqrt{6}}\$. Calculation of the RC block transmittance is quite harsh though.

Edit: this would be the same method for your low-pass filter version.

Answer (score 1):

**The shown circuit is a bad one** - why? Because the opamp is driven into deep saturation. As a consequence, the filtered output is not a "good" sinus signal. More than that, you need an additional ouput buffer for further processing of the filtered oscillation signal.

**One little modification** - and the circuit is much better: Connect the capacitor C3 not to ground but, instead to the output of the opamp.

Thus, you have an inverting integrator (phase sift +90 deg). Together with a phase shift (-90 deg) of the two remaining lowpass RC sections you can fulfill the oscillation condition as far as the phase is concerned. For a unity loop gain (amplitude condition) the value of C3 must be somewhat smaller than **C/12**. (C1=C2=C)

The frequency of oscillation is **wo=SQRT(3)/RC** (R1=R2=R; C1=C2=C)

As another advantage: A good-quality oscillation signal is available at a low-resistive opamp output (no additional buffer needed).

If you want to improve the quality of the signal, a soft-limiting technique can be incoroprated: Use a series connection of another (small) capacitor C4 and two anti-parallel diodes. This series combination is connected in parallel to C3 (select the parallel combination C3+C4>C/12).

Comment: The Circuit shown is a good one and can also be done with 3 stage HPF but demands a linear gain. Here the  Op Amp is simply a Comparator but the input is a good sine wave, 26.7 dB down if outputs are Rail-Rail to Vcc-Vee

Comment: But - you need a buffer for further processing. More than that, a soft-limiting path (a small non-linearity) is ALWAYS better than hard-limiting at the power rails. So - I don`t think that the original circuit (with an opamp without internal feedback) is a "good one". The signal quality is certainly not as good if compared with the classical integrator version.

Comment: It is actually very clean with fundamental down 27dB and 3rd harmonic down -6*3*2=36dB from fundamental or  63dB down from supply voltage so all you need is 20dB Gain or so.  This is a comparator design essentially not a linear op Amp like the HPF phase shift Osc

Comment: sorry -6db/octave *3rd order

Comment: So let me ask the other way round: Where are the advantages of the shown circuit (C3 grounded) if compared with "my" proposal (invertiing integrator, with C3 connected to the opamp output)?

Comment: That makes a linear gain circuit like the unstable Wien Osc that must be tweaked to increase gain to start up fast then then soft clipped to limit the amplitude but like the Wien uses an Op Amp in Linear mode and not a Comparator as TI also agree with me in Audioguru's post.. I'll add to my answer

Comment: Tony - I think, we should not forget the influence of the finite opamps input resistance upon oscillation frequency and amplitude (at the inverting input node). in particular when the external resistors are in the Meg-Ohm range.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the experts do it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to know the feedback network's gain is doing AC analysis using software.
[image]

In the picture you can simply see 180 degrees phase shift at about 0.177Hz, -29db. For voltage, using the formula db_value = 20log(voltage_gain) to find out the amplitude attenuation is about 1/29.